# Reminder Create Fails with NIL for Error Message

Tags: ios, error-handling, eventkit, ios6.1, reminders

I've been working on adding todo function to my app.  While everything seems to look right I get a failed create on the Reminder, but an error value of NIL.  Here's the relevant code - (I am pulling the text and the date from a UIViewController - everything is wired correctly).`

```
-(IBAction)createButtonPressed
{

    // Setup Variables for coverting date:
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;
    NSDate *actualDate;
    NSDateComponents *dateComps;
    NSCalendar  *calendar;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;

    actualDate = dateValue.date;
    calendar = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] copy];
    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[calendar timeZone]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
    year = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:actualDate] intValue];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
    month = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:actualDate] intValue];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
    day = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:actualDate] intValue];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];
    hour = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:actualDate] intValue];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm"];
    minute = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:actualDate] intValue];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ss"];
    second = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:actualDate] intValue];
    dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setTimeZone:[calendar timeZone]];
    [dateComps setDay:day];
    [dateComps setMonth:month];
    [dateComps setYear:year];
    // Create the Todo
    EKReminder *reminder = [EKReminder reminderWithEventStore:store];


    [reminder setTitle:self.actionText.text];

    [reminder setDueDateComponents:dateComps];

    EKCalendar *defaultReminderList = [store defaultCalendarForNewReminders];

    [reminder setCalendar:defaultReminderList];

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [store saveReminder:reminder
                                commit:YES
                                 error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error saving reminder: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        // Popup a messaging saying the reason why you can't create the todo.

    } else {
        // Popup a message saying the to do was created
    }


}
```

`The majority of this code is trying to get the date in correct format.  my NSLog shows the following:
"Error saving reminder: (null)"

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", store);` right before the reminder-saving and see what that gives you.

Comment: store is null... which must mean I don't have permission to access the calendar... From what I can tell

Comment: Check in Settings and make sure that the app has permission to access the calendars - Settings > Privacy > Calendars > Your App (should be ON)

Comment: That was it.. I found that my permissions part was not loading.. moved it into ViewDidLoad.. and all works!! Thanks!

Comment: Ohhh.. No rep for me :)

Comment: I had stared at this for too long.. your pointers were perfect.. kinda a "Doh!" moment for me.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the following code to the ViewDidLoad function

```
   // Add Todo Feature
    store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder
                          completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                              // Handle not being granted permission
                          }];
```